# Profile images not displaying in list

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to display profile images in a list of users. The list populates all names correctly however I'm having trouble displaying the profile images. The profile images have a separate collection and they're being stored using `slingshot` S3. The collection is publishing correctly because I can see all the data using `meteortoys:allthings`. I assume it my js file or how I'm trying to access them in the template. Let me know if you need more info.

Path: `userList.js`

```
Template.userList.helpers({
    userList: ()=> { 
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }}); 
    },
    profileImg: function(){
      return Files.find({userId: this._id});
    }
});
```

Path: `userList.html`

```
<template name="userList">

    {{#each userList}}

    {{#if profileImg url}}
        <img src="{{url}}" alt="{{url}}" class="profileImg">
    {{/if}}

        {{profile.firstName}} {{profile.familyName}}

    {{/each}}

</template>
```

Comment: What's the structure of a `File` document? E.g. what does `Files.findOne()` give you in the console?

Comment: Object {_id: "7dsdfsfs", url: "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/TTTT.jpg", userId: "TheUserId", added: Fri Mar 11 2016 10:21:19 GMT+1100 (AEDT)}

Comment: I've chaged all the unique info becuase I'm not sure what I should or should post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**userList.js**

```js
Template.userList.helpers({
  userList() {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() } });
  },

  profileImg() {
    return Files.findOne({ userId: this._id });
  },
});
```

**userList.html**

```html
<template name="userList">
  {{#each userList}}

    {{#with profileImg}}
      <img src="{{url}}" alt="{{url}}" class="profileImg">
    {{/with}}

    {{profile.firstName}} {{profile.familyName}}

  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The `with` will change the context for the `img` such that it actually has a `url` property. Returning the result of `findOne` in `profileImg` is also necessary here.

Comment: Thanks David. For some reason, that didn't work. I've found a solution which I've post. It's not elegant but it works.

Comment: Can you give the updated answer a try? It seems like that should work with minimal changes to your original code.

Comment: Bam! That works. Can you explain to me what you've changed?

Comment: I had to use `findOne` instead of `find`. The former returns a document which is necessary for `with` to work.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks!